# C# Image file information read location details and date

Tags: c#

I have images(Jpg, gif ,png etc..) local hard disk. What I need to read all file information such as location details latitude longitudes or location name and photos created date  each images. Please help me how do I read location details and date.

This is my C# code it not display location details or created date

```
 string directory = (@"C:\Photos");
 var AllImages = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.jpg",
                                   SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         .Select(Image.FromFile).ToList()
```

This is one of my photo example

.[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddt0dz7.aspx  There are also some libraries on CodeProject.  The term you want is `EXIF`

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate, this question is specifically asking for retrieval of image details and date, something which the linked answer does not provide.

Answer (score 4):

The keyword you're looking for is image metadata, or [EXIF data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format). You can read the raw data from the [`Image.PropertyItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.propertyitems.aspx) property and parse it manually, or you can use an external library to do the work for you.

I'd recommend [ExifLib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36342/ExifLib-A-Fast-Exif-Data-Extractor-for-NET-2-0) - it's a very basic yet capable library for reading EXIF data. Here's an example:

```
// Instantiate the reader
using (ExifReader reader = new ExifReader(@"C:\temp\testImage.jpg"))
{
    // Extract the tag data using the ExifTags enumeration
    DateTime datePictureTaken;
    if (reader.GetTagValue<DateTime>(ExifTags.DateTimeDigitized, out datePictureTaken))
    {
        // Do whatever is required with the extracted information
        MessageBox.Show(this, string.Format("The picture was taken on {0}", 
           datePictureTaken), "Image information", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

**Metadata Extractor dotnet**

As mentioned by others, an alternative is using the dotnet version of [metadata extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet).

Example to retrieve timestamp:

```
var directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(fileStream);
                var directory = directories.OfType<ExifSubIfdDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
                return directory?.GetDateTime(ExifDirectoryBase.TagDateTimeOriginal);
```

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015, do I install packages ExifLib. Also I need read all images folder. eg C:\Photos

Comment: Also check out [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet).

Comment: In case someone's coming here looking for a Unity compatible version: Metadata-Extractor seems to use .NET language features not available in the Unity .NET4.0 install of e.g. Unity 2019.3.0f6.